# C# force inherited class looping through list

Tags: c#

So for example I have two classes:

```
Class A
{
  string property1;
  string property2;
}

Class B : A
{
  string property3;
  string property4;
  ....
}
```

So B inherits class A's properties. They are sitting in a list, that is sitting in a dictionary

```
Dictionary <string, List<A>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<A>>();

List<A> myList = new List<A>();
```

There is one Dictionary, containing many List's, that all contain a mix of Class A & B objects. 
While looping through, I am trying to access some properties from Class B objects, I have an if statement to find them but the program still thinks they are of type Class A and throws an error when I try and use a property3 or property4. For example:

```
string key = string key in dictionary;
string index = object position in list;

myDictionary[key][index].property3.someMethod();
```

Is there a way to tell the program that this is a class B object and allow the properties 3 & 4 to be used?

Comment: You might want to rethink your algorithm if you are having to cast from base to derived. It's sometimes necessary, but it's a code smell (yes, I loathe that term, but it's apt here).

Comment: Yep, already smelly, and as soon as you start adding functionality to B , or deity forfend C and D which derive from A and B, ripe, truly ripe. Have a look at some other way, perhaps aggregation, before you get past the point of no return.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are getting at. What would be the point of using inheritance if you weren't going to add properties to the inherited class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the object safely as a B-type object, then check for null

```
var obj = myDictionary[key][index];

var bObj = obj as B;
if (bObj != null)
{
     bObj.someMethod();
}
```

Although, I would also probably say it seems like your design is off.  Ordinarily, I wouldn't expect something like this.  Normally,  if you're using inheritance, you'd want a design that allows them to be used interchangeably.  For example, you might implement the behavior on A as a no-op, but override it on B to actually do something.  This would make it so that consuming classes need not care whether the "A" thing is really an A or a B instance.

Comment: Excellent thank you, I know what you mean about design though, that was the first thing that came to mind but unfortunately this is university coursework and these were the classes we were given. Thanks